# Uniquely identify DiskStation in email report

Tags: email, configuration, synology, report

I'm administering multiple DiskStations, each of which sends out all its status reports to me. Unfortunately, in the default configuration all of these emails look the same and I often have a hard time figuring out which of my DiskStations actually sent the report. Is there a way to uniquely identify which DS sent such an email? I was thinking that it would be easiest if I could prefix every email subject with something like [servername] or [customstring].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved quite easily by changing default email notification properties.

Under **Control Panel -> Notification -> E-Mail**, change the **Subject Prefix** field according to each DiskStations's name or whatever you think will be useful for you to identify the device and then *Apply*.

All emails sent from the diskstations afterwards will have the *Subject Prefix* added in the Email subject.

If you want to customize more, check under: **Control Panel -> Notification -> Advanced**. Where you can customize each message template available in the system.

Comment: Well, that was too easy. Thanks a lot! This makes my life a whole lot easier.